# systemctl restart xxx versus systemctl restart xxx.service

Tags: centos, systemd, services

In the CentOS, I can use :

```
systemctl restart xxx
```

to restart a service, and can use:

```
systemctl restart xxx.service
```

to start a service too.

But if there is some difference here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man systemctl`:

> Parameter Syntax
>          Unit commands listed above take either a single unit name (designated as NAME), or multiple unit specifications (designated as
>          PATTERN...). In the first case, the unit name with or without a suffix must be given. If the suffix is not specified (unit name is
>          "abbreviated"), systemctl will append a suitable suffix, ".service" by default, and a type-specific suffix in case of commands
>          which operate only on specific unit types. For example,
>
> ```
>        # systemctl start sshd
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>        # systemctl start sshd.service
> ```
>
> are equivalent, as are
>
> ```
>        # systemctl isolate default
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>        # systemctl isolate default.target
> ```